# Newbie question: Stop() hide EnventListener

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs5

That seems a very simple question but I don't found anything on internet (or I don't enter the good words on google).

I try to implement a gallery of image with two buttons on each side of the picture to go to the next or the previous image. Very simple!

This is my code:

```
leftButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ButtonLeftHandler);
rightButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ButtonRightHandler);

function ButtonLeftHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
    trace("Mouse Button Left clicked");
    picIndex--;
    uiLoader.source = picIndex + ".jpg"; 
    gotoAndPlay(23);
} 

function ButtonRightHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
    trace("Mouse Button Right clicked");
    picIndex++;
    uiLoader.source = picIndex + ".jpg"; 
    gotoAndPlay(23);
} 

stop();
trace("Sequence Stopped");
```

uiLoader and picIndex are defined in a earlier frame..

On my output, I get

```
Sequence Stopped
```

When I clicked on a button. I don't get the trace message "Mouse button left..." My sequence is blocked.

Why ?!

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your buttons have to have the instance names you're using (*leftButton* and *rightButton*) assigned in the Properties panel. They also have to be available (on Stage) on the frame that is running this code.

Comment: The instances of my button are good defined on Properties panel. My buttons works when I'm running the sequence in loop... (without the stop())

Comment: The stop function shouldn't affect the event listeners. They're asynchronous. There is probably something else interfering on the Timeline.

Answer (score 0):

Ok the problem was I have a layer just in top of my button and it's hiding the button